# Notification icon detection

Tags: java, android, json

How can I make the colour change of notification icon when a new node is inserted in json that is fetch in notification menu in android.

Comment: Welcome! Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @sebasira I have created  a notification activity in which I push notification ,, the notification are fetched from json ,, i want that if a new notification is encountered the the notification icon color changes to red

Comment: Let me see if I understand.. you display a notification, let say the color is black. If a new notification arrive then you want to update it and set color to red?

Comment: @sebasira yes that is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

So if as in the comments, if what you want to do is display a notification with a color, and then update the same notification with a different color, you can try this:

First, when launching the notification set a fixed `notificationID`, for example:

```
notiManager.notify(123, notiBuilder.build());
```

I also think you may want to set the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` on the pending intent of your notification.

And to set the color of the notification:

```
notiBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

If you what to set a default color and then change it when a new one arrive I suggest you to save the count in the `SharedPreferences` and set the color according to the notification count